# Слайдер во всю страницу на JS

Tags: javascript

Где можно почитать урок что бы научиться делать как здесь? http://www.viasatpremium.ru/
Именно как сделать что бы был слайд на всю страницу, на любых мониторах, при любых разрешениях не вылазило... В какую сторону копать?

Comment: В первую очередь — курить справочники по CSS, HTML.

Answer (score 1):

Готовый урок для создания слайдера на всю ширину страницы ты вряд ли найдёшь.
Для начала почитай простое [создание слайдера на jQuery](http://ruseller.com/lessons.php?rub=32&id=1050)

Далее дело техники. 
Как вариант: поставить ширину не фиксированную, а width:100%; И при ресайзе пересчитывать размер шага

Либо скачай любой готовый плагин подобного слайдера и разберись как он работает. 
Вот пример слайдера растягивающегося на всю ширину экрана: [Parallax Content Slider](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2012/03/15/parallax-content-slider-with-css3-and-jquery/)